# Why CodeChef is Accepting only the 1st one And not the 2nd one? problem code in codechef - FCTRL2 contest code - PRACTICE

Tags: java, module, factorial

//this one is working fine in codechef.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Codechef smallFactorials = new Codechef();
    smallFactorials.runTestCase();
    
}
void runTestCase(){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int testCase;
    testCase = input.nextInt();
    while(testCase-- > 0) {
        int number;
        number = input.nextInt();
        BigInteger factorial=new BigInteger("1");
    while(number > 0) {
        factorial = factorial.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(number));
        number--;
    }
    System.out.println(factorial);
    }
}
```

//--------------------------------------------------x------------------------------------
//this one is not working and saying that its gives wrong answer.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int testCase;
    testCase = input.nextInt();
    while(testCase-- > 0) {
        int number;
        number = input.nextInt();
        BigInteger factorial=new BigInteger("1");
    while(number > 0) {
        factorial = factorial.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(number));
        number--;
    }
    System.out.println(factorial);
  }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be missing the end curly bracket for the `while(testCase-- > 0) {`

Comment: it is a typing mistake, sorry but my code is not working after fixing it.